# Comma in in php arrays in function signatures

Tags: php

I am going through the documentation of couple of PHP functions and I keep seeing the pattern of having a comma in the beginning of the arrays when used as function arguments as shown below:

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

More specifically

`[,array...] and [,int $offset]`..

Answer (score 2):

It is not an array with `,` in begining. Its an **optional parameters**. In General parameters in `[]` i.e. `square brackets` indicates that, Those parameters are optional. You can pass arguments only if needed. Otherwise you can skip it.